# How to get the count of element with non-empty-array-field when group in mongodb aggregate using Spring Data Mongo?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following documents in one collection named as `mail_test`. Some of them have a `tags` field which is an array:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("601a7c3a57c6eb4c1efb84ff"),
    "email" : "aaaa@bbb.com",
    "content" : "11111"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("601a7c5057c6eb4c1efb8590"),
    "email" : "aaaa@bbb.com",
    "content" : "22222"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("601a7c6d57c6eb4c1efb8675"),
    "email" : "aaaa@bbb.com",
    "content" : "33333",
    "tags" : [ 
        "x"
    ]
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("601a7c8157c6eb4c1efb86f4"),
    "email" : "aaaa@bbb.com",
    "content" : "4444",
    "tags" : [ 
        "yyy", 
        "zzz"
    ]
}
```

There are two documents with non-empty-tags, so I want the result to be 2.
I use the the following statement to aggregate and get the correct `tag_count`:

```
db.getCollection('mail_test').aggregate([{$group:{
    "_id":null,
    "all_count":{$sum:1},
    "tag_count":{"$sum":{$cond: [ { $ne: ["$tags", undefined] }, 1, 0]}}
    //if replace `undefined` with `null`, I got the tag_count as 4, that is not what I want
    //I also have tried `$exists`, but it cannot be used here.
}}])
```

and the result is:

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "all_count" : 4.0,
    "tag_count" : 2.0
}
```

and I use spring data mongo in java to do this:

```
private void test(){
        Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                Aggregation.match(new Criteria()),//some condition here
                Aggregation.group(Fields.fields()).sum(ConditionalOperators.when(Criteria.where("tags").ne(null)).then(1).otherwise(0)).as("tag_count")
                //I need an `undefined` instead of `null`,or is there are any other solution?
        );
        AggregationResults<MailTestGroupResult> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, MailTest.class, MailTestGroupResult.class);
        List<MailTestGroupResult> mappedResults = results.getMappedResults();
        int tag_count = mappedResults.get(0).getTag_count();
        System.out.println(tag_count);//get 4,wrong
    }
```

I need an `undefined` instead of `null` but I don't know how to do  this,or is there are any other solution?

Comment: Why do you need `undefined`? I think both `undefined` and `null` should not be used for checking the non-existence of a field.

Comment: I agree , but I don't know any other solution.What is your suggestion?

Comment: I posted couple of possibilities as an answer - one of them can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Aggregation operators to check if the field `tags` exists or *not* with one of the following constructs in the `$group` stage of your query (to calculate the `tag_count` value):

```
"tag_count":{ "$sum": { $cond: [ { $gt: [ { $size: { $ifNull: ["$tags", [] ] }}, 0 ] }, 1, 0] }}

// - OR -

"tag_count":{ "$sum": { $cond: [ $eq: [ { $type: "$tags" }, "array" ] }, 1, 0] }
```

Both, return the same result (as you had posted).

Comment: You are right. But how to write it in java ? I have tried this:

`Aggregation.group(Fields.fields()).sum(ConditionalOperators.when(Criteria.where("tags.size").gt(0)).then(1).otherwise(0)).as("tag_count")`


the result is correct but I still want to exclude the null values explicitly. I don't know how to use `$ifNull` here.

Comment: _"...I still want to exclude the null values explicitly"_. Are you saying that a document can have `tags: null`?

Comment: For now , no. But I want to make the situation a little more complex so that I can get more skills to do more complex aggregation in the future.I want to know how to translate mongodb script into java code strictly.

Comment: _For now , no._ In such case, the above two will work fine. You are using Spring Data MongoDB (which uses MongoDB Java driver) - lookup the API docs (the appropriate version). I generally, browse the APIs and figure by trying only.

Comment: Another option is, you can use a `$facet` stage with two facets - one with tags and one for all. The first facet can have a match stage, which will filter the documents without tags field. Then count the documents. The second facet just count the documents. It will be easy writing the code using Spring Data APIs. This eliminates the group stage and all its complex conditions.

Comment: Thanks. I have not noticed the `$facet` function before.